# How to perform linq search with spaces

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I have a linq query that takes data from sql table .
In my database values written with the spaces after value like this :
"Johny      (and 5 spaces after that) ". 
When i try to find "Johny" - (without spaces)query didn't work. But when i search  "Johny                 " (after Johny -  5 spaces, it didnt show there) -it works.
 because I can't change something in base , i didn't have permission for this .
How can i make it work without spaces - changing only my query?
My code :

```
var fidn = (repository.users.Join(repository.usersLG, 
                                  post => post.pcod ,    
                                  meta => meta.pcod,  
                                  (post, meta) => new { Post = post, Meta = meta }) 
                             .Where(postAndMeta => postAndMeta.Post.fam_v == "Johny           ").ToList())
                             .Select(x => new  Final { 
                                 mcod = x.Post.mcod,
                                 pcod = x.Post.pcod, 
                                 c_ogrn = x.Post.c_ogrn, 
                                 fam_v = x.Post.fam_v, 
                                 im_v = x.Post.im_v,
                                 ot_v = x.Post.ot_v,
                                 idGK = x.Meta.idGK });
```

Asp net web page c# entity framework

Comment: you could use `fam_v.StartsWith("Johny")` instead of `==`

Comment: It sounds like the field is a fixed-width character field (e.g. `CHAR(10)`). If that's the case just pad your search term to the width of the field.

Comment: @heinzbeinz That would match `JohnyBoy` too which may not be correct.

Comment: @DStanley you're right. fam_v.Trim() == "Johny" should work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Trim`: (*and also in this case consider changing to the query syntax, IMO more readable when it comes to joins*)

```
var fidn = from post in repository.users 
           join meta in repository.usersLG on post.pcod equals meta.pcod
           where post.fam_v.Trim() == "Johny"
           select new Final {
               mcod = post.mcod,
               pcod = post.pcod, 
               c_ogrn = post.c_ogrn, 
               fam_v = post.fam_v, 
               im_v = post.im_v,
               ot_v = post.ot_v, 
               idGK = meta.idGK
           };
```

*Aslo have a look at [C# naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002(v=vs.110).aspx) for the names of the properties in the `Final` object*

Answer (score 5):

Use [`Trim`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738534(v=vs.110).aspx) method, it's supported by EF:

```
 //...
 .Where(postAndMeta => postAndMeta.Post.fam_v.Trim() == "Johny") 
 //...
```

Comment: Good to know ;). Yes, EF supports some string methods which are translated to canonical functions in sql. You will find then in the link I quoted in my answer.

Comment: @octavioccl - you were there before me with the `Trim()`. You deserve the credit

Comment: thanks @GiladGreen, I sincerely appreciate your gesture, but it's better if we can share the credit ;).